# How to refresh page from content script? - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, design-patterns, google-chrome-extension

Sounds simple but I didn't find any questions/answers for this.

Every one tells you how to refresh the page from **popup.js** or **background.js**

Is there a more efficient way than sending a message to **background.js** and running the script below?

```js
// Reload page
          chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
          });
```

...And if there's not, could you answer with a clean, efficient implementation of that?

*(P.S. tabs.query does not work on **content.js** if you did not know.)*

Comment: You're missing something here. Having just that script would repeatedly reload the current tab. In other words, what you're asking depends on context. Also, this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Context: Reload the tab once after performing a task

Comment: What task? Where?

Comment: There are several contexts that could be available to an extension, each with different purposes. Generally, work should be done in the background context. Because of this, reloading the tab is best done there as well. The next best would be the content script context (or, indirectly, the page context), assuming the work needs to interact with the page. All the other contexts either don't have the right kind of access or are ephemeral and should be setup to instead ask the background context to do the reload.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I've implemented it into the background. (I'm new to chrome extensions so don't really understand the structure of it)

Comment: It's `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

As Ouroborus says in the comment above:

> There are several contexts that could be available to an extension, each with different purposes. Generally, work should be done in the background context. Because of this, reloading the tab is best done there as well. The next best would be the content script context (or, indirectly, the page context), assuming the work needs to interact with the page. All the other contexts either don't have the right kind of access or are ephemeral and should be setup to instead ask the background context to do the reload.

To any future viewers, I've implemented it in my chrome extension like so:

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.message === "refresh")
      try {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
        });
        sendResponse({message:"OK", status: "200", data: null});
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        sendResponse({message: error.message, status: "500", data: null});
        return false;
      }
    }
);
```

**content.js**

```js
function refresh() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message:"refresh"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.message);
    });
}
```

Now, in my **content.js** code, I can just use:

```js
refresh()
```

Very clean and simple.